# Nested case limit

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use nested case but SQL is giving me an error on 10 limit. Below is my sql. Do you have any suggestions for me?

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vwOpti_ChannelPreference] AS
SELECT SUB.*, 
CASE WHEN PCYCResponse + JBIResponse > 1 THEN 'SF Multi' 
 ELSE CASE WHEN MDLResponse + SermoResponse + BioPharmResponse + MedscapeResponse + PharmaConnectResponse + THResponse 
               + OtherResponse > 1 THEN 'MCM Multi' 

 ELSE CASE WHEN MDLResponse + SermoResponse + BioPharmResponse + MedscapeResponse + PharmaConnectResponse + THResponse 
               + PCYCResponse + JBIResponse + OtherResponse > 1 THEN 'SF & MCM Multi'

 ELSE CASE WHEN MDLResponse + SermoResponse + BioPharmResponse + MedscapeResponse + PharmaConnectResponse + THResponse 
               + PCYCResponse + JBIResponse + OtherResponse = 0 THEN 'None'

 ELSE CASE WHEN MDLResponse = 1 THEN 'MDL' 
 ELSE CASE WHEN SermoResponse = 1 THEN 'Sermo'
 ELSE CASE WHEN BioPharmResponse = 1 THEN 'BioPharmCommunications' 
 ELSE CASE WHEN MedscapeResponse = 1 THEN 'Medscape'
 ELSE CASE WHEN PharmaConnectResponse = 1 THEN 'PharmaConnect'
 ELSE CASE WHEN THResponse = 1 THEN 'Targeted Healthcare'
 ELSE CASE WHEN PCYCResponse = 1 THEN 'PCYC'
 ELSE CASE WHEN JBIResponse = 1 THEN 'JBI'
ELSE CASE WHEN OtherResponse = 1 THEN 'Other' 
END END END END END END END END END END END END AS ChannelPref
FROM (  SELECT CC.*, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN MTE.DesignVendor = 'MDL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MDLResponse, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN MTE.DesignVendor = 'Sermo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SermoResponse, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN MTE.DesignVendor = 'BioPharmCommunications' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BioPharmResponse, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN MTE.DesignVendor = 'Medscape' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MedscapeResponse, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN MTE.DesignVendor = 'PharmaConnect' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PharmaConnectResponse, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN MTE.DesignVendor = 'Targeted Healthcare' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS THResponse, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN MTE.DesignVendor = 'PCYC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PCYCResponse, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN MTE.DesignVendor = 'JBI' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS JBIResponse, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN MTE.DesignVendor NOT IN ('MDL','Sermo', 'BioPharmCommunications', 'Medscape', 'PharmaConnect', 
                                               'Targeted Healthcare', 'PCYC', 'JBI') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OtherResponse
        --SELECT DISTINCT MTE.CHANNELNAME
        FROM slice_CampaignContact CC 
        --LEFT JOIN slice_MktgTactic MTI ON I.MktgTacticID = MTI.MktgTacticID AND I.SliceDate = MTI.SliceDate
        LEFT JOIN slice_Engagements E ON CC.ContactID = E.ContactID AND CC.SliceDate = E.SliceDate
        LEFT JOIN slice_MktgTactic MTE ON E.MktgTacticID = MTE.MktgTacticID AND E.SliceDate = MTE.SliceDate 
        GROUP BY CC.SliceDate, CC.BrandCd, CC.ContactID, CC.SyncID, CC.FirstName, CC.LastName, CC.CampaignName, 
        ClientSegment, ControlSegmentName) SUB
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the ELSE CASE every time -- that is just the way CASE works -- each WHEN is only checked on when prior WHENs fail.  Like this:

```
SELECT SUB.*, 
 CASE
  WHEN PCYCResponse + JBIResponse > 1 THEN 'SF Multi' 
  WHEN MDLResponse + SermoResponse + BioPharmResponse + MedscapeResponse + PharmaConnectResponse + THResponse + OtherResponse > 1 THEN 'MCM Multi' 
  WHEN MDLResponse + SermoResponse + BioPharmResponse + MedscapeResponse + PharmaConnectResponse + THResponse + PCYCResponse + JBIResponse + OtherResponse > 1 THEN 'SF & MCM Multi'
  WHEN MDLResponse + SermoResponse + BioPharmResponse + MedscapeResponse + PharmaConnectResponse + THResponse + PCYCResponse + JBIResponse + OtherResponse = 0 THEN 'None'
  WHEN MDLResponse = 1 THEN 'MDL' 
  WHEN SermoResponse = 1 THEN 'Sermo'
  WHEN BioPharmResponse = 1 THEN 'BioPharmCommunications' 
  WHEN MedscapeResponse = 1 THEN 'Medscape'
  WHEN PharmaConnectResponse = 1 THEN 'PharmaConnect'
  WHEN THResponse = 1 THEN 'Targeted Healthcare'
  WHEN PCYCResponse = 1 THEN 'PCYC'
  WHEN JBIResponse = 1 THEN 'JBI'
  WHEN OtherResponse = 1 THEN 'Other' 
  ELSE 'Woah, nothing matched'
 END AS ChannelPref
FROM (  SELECT CC.*, -- etc
```

Comment: @Anu - If this solved your problem you click the check mark to the left.